# Services provided by the different Java EE containers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am reading this book [Beginning Java™ EE 6 Platform with GlassFish™ 3: From Novice to Professional](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219548)  and I have a question to the image below. I thought I have read somewhere the services such as Web Services are only provided in the EJB Container but from the image below (that shows the services provided by each container: quote book) it seems like the Web Container does provided that service too. Is that correct or have I misinterpreted the image and the image text? And if that is correct then it means that I can package my application as a WAR and deploy it to a Web Container and still use Web Services API?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone corrects me if I'm wrong, but historically it's a bit other way around: it is a EJB service that is able now to be annotated as a `@WebService`.

So yes, both web and ejb containers can provide web services. And yes, your web service can be packaged in a single war.

Answer (score 1):

Caching, pooling, naming, life-cycle management and RMI

Answer (score 0):

As Osw already remarked, the concepts are blending together.

In an EAR application, you can have separate web and EJB modules. EJB modules traditionally focussed on business logic, reachable by local or remote (RPC/RMI) invocations. Since one usage of web services is RPC, it made sense to give the EJB module support for those technologies. From a pure technical standpoint it's basically just another protocol to do RPC.

However, the concepts of web module and web service naturally overlap as well, so of course the web module supports this technique too (not in the least because web services are about more than just RPC).

Further blurring the lines is the fact that EJB beans were once dedicated to be put into the EJB module, but nowadays can be used used just as well in the web module.

Future versions of Java EE are likely to blur the lines even more, when many of the container services (like transactions, pooling, etc) that are now properties of EJB beans will be decoupled from them and made available via CDI annotations, so they can be applied to all "web components" directly.

In that way, the web module is truly a superset of the EJB module.

The function of the EJB module remains that it allows you to have a layer of functionality beneath the web layer that is isolated via class loaders. This means the web module can reference classes that you define in the EJB module, but not the other way around. Additionally, pure presentation techniques like Servlet, JSP and JSF are not available in the EJB module and there are at the moment no plans at all to make those techniques also available there.